# Do variables declared inside callback functions remain in memory or are they destroyed upon end of callback execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, theory, ram

I have this code snippet; It basically connects to mongo database and goes through documents. On each iteration it searches for messages array of objects. It creates variable of messages, and then loops through it. **Does declared variable (`var msg`) inside callback function remain in memory or is it destroyed upon end of callback function execution?** Would there be any difference if `var msg` was actually declared as `let msg`? Is there a way to discard whole scope from the memory?

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, (err, db) => {
  assert.equal(null,err);
  var collection_data = db.collection('threadContents').find();
  collection_data.on('data', (doc) => {
    var msg = doc.messages;
    for (var variable in msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    }//forin(msg)
  });//collection_data.on
});//mongo.connect
```

Comment: `is it destroyed upon end of callback function execution?` - often it is, it really depends on the code

Comment: @JaromandaX I provided sample code snippet. Otherwise, which is recommended way to force variable destruction upon the end of callback function execution?

Comment: oh, are you asking about your specific code? which variable are you concerned with?

Comment: @JaromandaX There is a description. Inside on('data') callback function, var msg is declared. Is it destroyed or it still remains in memory?

Comment: yes, it will be "garbage collected"

Comment: @Kunok There is no closure so it will be GCed sometime however it would be nice to nullify it along with `doc.messages` (`msg = null; doc.messages = null;` ) once you finish with your loop.

Comment: @Redu Thanks for advice, that was something I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory - yes.
In practice - it's not that simple...

In your example, `var msg` does not "leak" outside of it's original scope, so it will most likely get destroyed when callback finishes it's job.
One thing to note - the destruction of this object doesn't have to happen immediately - JS Engines are mostly Garbage Collected, so this piece of memory can stay on the stack for some time, but it won't be reachable anymore.

If you would declare this variable in outer scope, it could possibly stay in the memory if that scope stayed in memory (so, other pieces of code could access that variable). You can read about this behavior in [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) section at MDN.

Another thing to note is usage of `console.log`. In general, non-primitive values (like Objects or Arrays, which actually are "special" objects), will be accessible by reference, not by value. Therefore, if your `var msg` is a non-primitive, it will most likely persist in the memory until you clear your console. Primitive values would be copied, so strictly speaking they would still persist in the memory, but probably in another place in the memory (although JIT engines could probably try to optimize that and don't copy the memory if it's not necessary).

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "Clear your console?"

Comment: Click the "clear" button in the console of course :)

Comment: I actually run node scripts from terminal and there is no such option and that is not something I would like to depend on, since I am trying to use the least possible RAM for my script which needs to do some really heavy work on not so powerful hardware and I run these scripts as CRON jobs.

Comment: In Node's case you don't have to worry about it, as Node simply "prints" the value to the screen/terminal and forgets about it. However, if you would use some kind of interactive node inspector, the value would most likely persist, as you would have the ability to closely inspect logged values.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js (and all javascript engines) rely on [tracing garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection), which means that allocated memory is deallocated in a non-deterministic way, i.e. you cannot predict exactly when it will happen. This usually does not affect you, but uif you really want some chunk of memory or some other resource to be deallocated in a predictable way, you have to use some ad-hoc technique.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example 'msg' will be deleted, but don't expect it to be deleted straight away.

Comment: Upon which event would JavaScript delete it later (not straight away) ?

Comment: What i meant was that it is not predictable to say when that will happen.

Comment: Is there any documentation related to that?

Comment: check this to begin with https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/